# TestNG run set of test cases in loop

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Searched everywhere but could not find solution how to do following:
As Example:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
@Test
public void test1(){
assertThat(assertvalue 1);
}

@Test
public void test2(){
assertThat(assertvalue 2);
}
@Test
public void test3(){
assertThat(assertvalue 3);
}
}
```

Of course I can use dataProvider or invocationCount and do all asserts in one test case, but if one assert will fail whole test case fail. I want kind of separate one big test case for 3 small test cases
Any help appreciated

Comment: Can you update the question with your exact _usecase_ why you are opting for loop on a set of `@Test` annotated methods?

Answer (score 1):

Having dependencies between test cases is discouraged. You could achieve a similar result--checking each value 1-5 without short-circuiting and stopping after a failure on 2--using `SoftAssert`.

```
SoftAssert soft = new SoftAssert();
soft.fail("Failure # 1\n");
soft.fail("Failure # 2");
soft.assertAll();
```

should output:

> The following assertions failed:
>   Failure # 1
>   Failure # 2

Answer (score 0):

I tried following code:

```
public class SimpleTest {
    private String param = "";
    public SimpleTest(String param) {
        this.param = param;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("Before SimpleTest class executed.");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        System.out.println("testMethod parameter value is: " + param);
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "testMethod1")
    public void testMethod2() {
        System.out.println("testMethod parameter value is: " + param);
    }
}

public class SimpleTestFactory{
@Factory
public Object[] factoryMethod() {
    return new Object[] {
            new SimpleTest("one"),
            new SimpleTest("two")
    };
}
```

And tried following code and it does not keep order

Comment: this won't work until and unless u've marked group-by-instances as true..so mark that first as @julien has explained

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Works with group-by-instances = true. But only when you pass values "one", "two", "tree" in my example to `new SimpleTest()` it does not take them in sequential order. It can take "one", "three", "two" or other combinations. Is it expected behavior or I missed something? Thank you in advance

Comment: @IlyaG Include this code attempt as an observation to edit and update the main question. This area is for complete Answers and your update may be deleted soon !!!

Answer (score 0):

Add invocationCount

```
@Test(priority = 350, groups = "success" ,invocationCount = 10)
    public void test1(){
        assertThat(assertvalue 1);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use "property",if you want to execute test1(),add "priority =1"

```
       @Test
        public void test1(priority =1){
          System.out.println("execute frist");;
        }

        @Test
        public void test2(priority =2){
          assertThat(assertvalue 2);
        }
        @Test
        public void test3(priority =3){
          assertThat(assertvalue 3);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Test
  public void main() throws IOException,InterruptedException
{
    FileInputStream fil = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\V-DKumaravelu\\ECM Data\\ECM-Data-Sheet.xlsx"));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(fil);
    XSSFSheet sheet=workbook.getSheet("ECM");
    int count=sheet.getLastRowNum();
    System.out.println(count);

        for (int i=1;i<=5;i++){

            Snapshot sc = new Snapshot();

        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
        String ServiceDate=cell.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("DOSate is "+ ServiceDate);
        XSSFCell cell1=row.getCell(1);
        String MemberID=cell1.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("Member "+MemberID);
        XSSFCell cell2 = row.getCell(2);
        String FacilityCode=cell2.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("Facility Code "+FacilityCode);
        XSSFCell cell3=row.getCell(3);
        String ReleaseOfInfo=cell3.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("ROI " + ReleaseOfInfo);
        XSSFCell cell4 = row.getCell(4);
        String ContactName=cell4.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("Contact Name " + ContactName);
        XSSFCell cell5=row.getCell(5);
        String ContactPhoneAreaCode=cell5.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("ContactPhoneAreaCode " + ContactPhoneAreaCode);
        XSSFCell cell6 = row.getCell(6);
        String ContactPhonePrefix=cell6.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("ContactPhoePrefix " + ContactPhonePrefix);
        XSSFCell cell7=row.getCell(7);
        String ContactPhoneLine=cell7.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("ContactPhoneLine " + ContactPhoneLine);
        XSSFCell cell8=row.getCell(8);
        String ContactPhoneExt=cell8.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("ContactPhoneExt " + ContactPhoneExt);
        XSSFCell cell9 = row.getCell(9);
        String ServiceType=cell9.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("ServiceType " + ServiceType);
        XSSFCell cell10=row.getCell(10);
        String ServiceLevel=cell10.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("ServiceLevel " + ServiceLevel);
        XSSFCell cell11=row.getCell(11);
        String PRIS=cell11.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("PRIS " + PRIS);
        XSSFCell cell12 = row.getCell(12);
        String DiagnosisCode=cell12.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("Diagosis " + DiagnosisCode);
        XSSFCell cell13=row.getCell(13);
        String ProcedureCode=cell13.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("Procedure Code " + ProcedureCode);
        XSSFCell cell14=row.getCell(14);
        String unitsProcedure=cell14.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("Procedure Units " + unitsProcedure);


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\V-DKumaravelu\\eclipse-workspace\\ECM Portal\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://10.32.52.79:8888/ECM/clientlogin.aspx");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserId")).sendKeys("203861P");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("RETINA01");          
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'_ctl7_lbNewPA\']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("outpatientServices2")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("serviceDate")).sendKeys(ServiceDate);
        driver.findElement(By.id("memberID")).sendKeys(MemberID);
        sc.main(driver);
        driver.findElement(By.id("nextLink1")).click();
        Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("facilityCode")));
        select .selectByVisibleText(FacilityCode);
        Select select1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("releaseOfInfo")));
        select1 .selectByVisibleText(ReleaseOfInfo);
        driver.findElement(By.id("ContactName")).sendKeys(ContactName);
        driver.findElement(By.id("ContactPhoneAreaCode")).sendKeys(ContactPhoneAreaCode);
        driver.findElement(By.id("ContactPhonePrefix")).sendKeys(ContactPhonePrefix);
        driver.findElement(By.id("ContactPhoneLine")).sendKeys(ContactPhoneLine);
        driver.findElement(By.id("ContactPhoneExt")).sendKeys(ContactPhoneExt);
        sc.main(driver);
        driver.findElement(By.id("nextLink1")).click();
        Select select2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='serviceType']")));
        select2 .selectByVisibleText(ServiceType);
        Select select3 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'levelOfService\']")));
        select3 .selectByVisibleText(ServiceLevel);
        driver.findElement(By.id("facilityPris")).sendKeys(PRIS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("diagnosisCode")).sendKeys(DiagnosisCode);
        driver.findElement(By.id("addDiagnosis")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("codeProcedure")).sendKeys(ProcedureCode);
        driver.findElement(By.id("unitsProcedure")).sendKeys(unitsProcedure);
        driver.findElement(By.id("addProcedure")).click();
        sc.main(driver);
        driver.findElement(By.id("nextLink2")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnSubmit")).click(); 
        sc.main(driver);
        Assert.assertNotNull(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'Table1\']/tbody/tr[5]/td[6]")),"Failed");
driver.close();
}}

}
```

Comment: I tried to execute a script via TestNG annotation . I do have a loop where i will get 'n' test executed when my variable i='n'. But instead only i am getting the whole script as a single test. Please help me for getting 'n' test executed